# Mail.Send permission on Calendar.ReadWrite Application Access

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, exchange-server, azure-ad-graph-api

1. I have an application and I wanted to create a meeting event in the
   user's Outlook Calendar.
2. In my AzureAd application, I am planning to give
   "Calendar.ReadWrite" Application Permission.
3. Do I need to give Mail.Send permission to send a meeting invite from the user Calendar?
   Or Calendar.ReadWrite permission is enough?

Comment: Hi do you have any other concerns? If my answer is helpful, you can accept it. Thank you:)

Comment: Yes.. Your answer is helpful. Thank you very much.
I will mark it solved, once I test it in my environment. So that it would be helpful for everyone

Comment: Any updates? Did you test it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Calendar.ReadWrite` permission is enough.

Event meeting invitation will be sent **Automatically**.